# Where does the extra energy come during superelastic collison

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, particle-physics, collision

It is known that in superelastic collison the energy of particles after collison is more than the original particles but how is it possible . I barely could find suitable information on net for a high school student . These are some conceptions I have about such collisions

---

- these collisions must be endothermic or I should say must be initiated by some agent to increase the net energy
- I feel nucleur collisons can be an example for such collisons because the output energy in nucleur collisions are quite high
  Can anybody verify them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any collision that results in the release of potential energy, leaving a net positive change in kinetic energy, is considered to be superelastic. Consider a compressed spring with some sort of trigger mechanism. Or, if you consider exothermic chemical reactions as ballistic collisions, they might also be considered superelastic. Exothermic reactions release bond energy as heat, which is in its simplest form just kinetic energy on an atomic scale. The same would be true for nuclear reactions.